# How to pick only video from gallery in Android using Titanium?

Tags: android, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

```
Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
    mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO],
    videoMaximumDuration : 10000,
    videoQuality : Titanium.Media.QUALITY_MEDIUM,
    allowEditing : false,
    success : function(e) {
    },
    error : function(error) {
    }
});
```

This works in ios. 
mediaTypes : Titanium.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO is only for ios.

How we can show only video from gallery in android using titanium.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For android you can use intents.

```
    var intent = Titanium.Android.createIntent({
        action : Ti.Android.ACTION_PICK,
        type : "video/*"
    });

    intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    var activity = Titanium.Android.currentActivity;
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, function(e) { if (e.error) { ...} else { ...}}:
```